# How to insert meta-tag robots in typo3 tx_news in paginated list

Tags: typo3, tx-news

is it possible to insert a meta-tag robots->noindex in paginated pages of the list - not in the first but in  all other?

typo3 8.7 - tx_news 6.3.0

cu
Volker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the solution (for me) is to insert

```
<f:if condition="{pagination.current}>=2">
    {v:page.header.meta(name: 'robots', content: 'NOINDEX,FOLLOW')}
</f:if>
```

into viewhelpers/widget/paginate/index.html

vhs-extension is allready installed.

cu 
Volker

Answer (score 1):

To modify the `<head/>` content you should install `vhs` extension which provides useful viewhelpers, also to manipulate the `<head/>` content.

VHS extension: https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/vhs/

VHS docs: https://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/vhs/master.html

There you will find also how can you add this viewhelper in your templates.

Syntax you will need is `<vhs:page.header.meta property="" content="" />` https://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/vhs/master/Page/Header/MetaViewHelper.html

Answer (score 0):

You can try to fetch the page GET params and build an condition of it:

```
[globalVar = GP:tx_news_pi1|@widget_0|currentPage > 1]
  page.meta.robots = noindex
[GLOBAL]
```

Please watch at the zero of `@widget_0`. Normaly this should 0 but if you have configured another widget id you have the change the condition

Comment: thanks a lot - I found a solution for this problem.

cu 
Volker